# Page is not reading css from wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, font-awesome

I changed a font-size from 20px to 40px and page can't read a CSS. I'm using WordPress.

clearing catch is not working. I thinking its some problem reading from css. WHen i am changin value in f12 from 20 to 40 in exacly this position size is changing.

**HTML**

```
 <div>
      <div class="row_205"> 
                <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="font-icon-19 fa fa-facebook-f" ></i></a><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="font-icon-19 fa fa-instagram"></i></a>               
      </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fa.font-icon-19 {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 40px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    
}

.fa.font-icon-19:hover {
    text-rendering: auto;
    color:#3F464C;
    
}

.fa.font-icon-19:active {
    text-rendering: auto;
}
```

That is .fa function --->

```
.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

[image: Screen #1]

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. Odds are is that there are other, more specific CSS rules in play that override yours.

Comment: And a more WordPress-specific dupicate: [CSS not updating in browser when I change it](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/107513/css-not-updating-in-browser-when-i-change-it) Please search before posting next time.

Comment: Try this: `font-size: 40px !important;` Adding !Important should prioritize your css.